# Copied text disappears

Tags: lock-screen, keyboard

If I highlight some text and copy it to the clipboard (with the intention of pasting it somewhere later), then lock my phone, then unlock it, the text will no longer be on the clipboard.

How can I ensure that copied text will remain copied after locking and unlocking the phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows phone 8.1 the copied text or clipboard text will disappear after you lock your phone. This problem is **fixed in Windows 10 mobile**. There is no solution to this until the Windows 10 update arrives to your device.

Note : You can use note taking apps to preserve your text while locking your phone in WP8.1